# How to use 74LS245 to level up signals form 3.3V to 5V?

Tags: lcd, level-shifting, 5v, 3.3v

I am using FPGA 3.3 V outputs to drive 16x4 character LCD (5 V). I went through the data sheet [74LS245](http://www.futurlec.com/74LS/74LS245.shtml) and found this can be operated at Vcc 5 V and accept input voltages from 2 V. I am confused because data sheet has not mentioned the output voltage up to 5 V, will this IC suitable for my application?

Comment: Check LCD specs. Most likely has same TTL input thresholds and hence work straight off your 3.3V FPGA if you set its outputs in CMOS mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does mention it. Search for V<sub>OH</sub> You will find that it is inadequate: It will only guarantee that V<sub>OH</sub> is above 2 volts under worst condition, and above 2.7 volts under "good" conditions.

Typically you'd want to take a look at the [74**HCT**245](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT245.pdf). It has a higher guaranteed output but a 2 volt input threshold even when driven at 5 volts.

Comment: will this ( 74HCT245) IC suitable for my application?3.3V inputs at VCC 5V to get 5V outputs?

Comment: @iopertyki 74LSxxx is TTL and input threshold is 1.5V (between 0&1) and 74HCTxxx uses same input threshold in CMOS with full output swing unlike true TTL, while 74HCxxx like most CMOS input threshold is Vcc/2 +/-x%, so YES 'HCT' it will work. T designates TTL input thresholds of 1.5V is centred enough on 3.3V ok.